# How can I remove (blank) results from a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

To clarify the question I do not want to filter out blank results, nor do I want to conditionally format (blank) to not show up.

I require the ability to copy all the data in my pivot table and paste it as values into a new sheet. If I simply format to show (blank) as blank when i copy and paste the data (the word (blank)) still comes across. I need a way to make that cell in the pivot table truly be blank.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you saying that you copy a cell that is empty (or perhaps contains the value "") and when you paste it, you get the value "(blank)"? If that isn't what you mean, please edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: Are you saying that you have some cells that contain the literal string "(blank)", and you want to convert those to actually be blank?

Comment: In a pivot table when a cell a row that the table is drawing data for s empty it populates that cell in the pivot table with the value "blank".
I am after a way to have that cell be truly blank, not just formatted to not show the value "blank", but truly empty.